# How to highlight border of sap.m.table cell when hovered over?

Tags: html, css, sapui5

I have this table: https://jsbin.com/jibevalope/edit?html,css,js,output and i'm trying to highlight the individual cell that is hovered over.

I have tried adding

```
mode="SingleSelectMaster" modeAnimationOn="false"
```

but this just highlights the entire row of the cell that is hovered over.

How do I focus on only the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.sapMListTblCell:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.sapMListTblRow:hover {
  background-color: #f9fbfc;
}
```

This will make it so when you hover over the cell, the background color of the row will remain the default color and the cell will be colored white. You need both rules to override the tables row hover CSS and to add your cell hover CSS.